# Lookup by column name

Tags: pandas, lookup

How do I use one column (X) to look up a value using the column heading of another dataframe (df_2) please?

For example:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'X' : [ 1,  2,  1,  1,  1,  2,  1,  2,  2,  1]})

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'1' : ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'],
                     '2' : ['b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','a']})
```

The result that I'm aiming for is:

```
                             a   c   c   d   e   g   g   i   j   j
```

I tried:

```
for index, row in df_1.iterrows():
    df_1['Y'] = df_2[df_1['X'][index]]
```

But I got:

```
KeyError: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`lookup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) with casting column `X` to string, thanks @Zero:

```
a = df_2.lookup(df_2.index, df_1.X.astype(str))
print (a)
['a' 'c' 'c' 'd' 'e' 'g' 'g' 'i' 'j' 'j']
```

Comment: Here is an embelishment to your approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53417435/lookup-with-missing-labels/53419309